# Ajax Return Button Not Work (PHP file included)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to send some data by using the kill button and get the item back. but it not works. the button with ajax function.

4 files: index.php, script.js, actionplay.php, actionpickup.php.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="submit_buttonplay">Kill</button>
<div id="show"><span2></span2></div>
```

script.js

```
function button(name,url) {
$('#'+name).click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url:url+'.php',
      success: function(html){
      $('#'+'show').after(html);
      }
   });
return false;
});
}

$(function(){
    button('submit_buttonplay','actionplay');
});


$(function() {
$('#'+'submit_buttonpickup').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'actionpickup.php',
      success: function(data) {
      if (data == "Picked!") {
      $('button').hide();
      $('span2').text('Picked!').show().fadeOut(5000);
      } else {
      $('#'+'show').after(data);
      }
      }
   });
return false;
});
})
```

actionplay.php

```
<?php
echo "<button type=\"submit\" id=\"submit_buttonpickup\">ITEM</button>";
?>
```

actionpickup.php

```
<?php
echo "Picked!";
?>
```

they not works, so I try using test.php to do the job of index.php.

test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="submit_buttonpickup">ITEM</button>
<div id="show"><span2></span2></div>
```

the button works.

I don't know why.
I clicked the link in index.php, it show me the same button:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_buttonpickup">ITEM</button>
```

but not works, test.php show me the button can work,
how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please indent your JS code in a way that makes it readable.

Comment: just modified. hope that helps.

Comment: `$(submit_buttonpickup)` - there is no variable named `submit_buttonpickup` anywhere in your code.

Comment: id="submit_buttonpickup", it is the name. and this is why test.php works.

Comment: submit_buttonpickup is not defined problem solved, but the problem of button still exists.